# How can i optimize this query for a faster execution time

Tags: sql, oracle

this is my query

```
select case t.type
when 'N' then  (select count(*) from table10_other)
when 'L' then (select count(*) from table11_other)
when 'P' then (select count(*) from table12_other)
end as nlp, t.* 
from table t  
left outer join employee e on e.emp_id = t.emp_id
left outer join table2 t2 on t2.code= t.code and d.year = t.year 
order by e.name
```

including the ORDER BY part significantly slows down my query.

Comment: which RDBMS? It isn't all of them....

Comment: Do you really want a left join to a table if you're going to order by one of the fields it returns?

Comment: @MitchWheat PL/SQL

Comment: @JohnHC Yeap, it works

Comment: @jaraisyn. The query doesn't make sense. Please describe what are you trying to achieve, business wise.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz optimize this query(select) to work faster

Comment: @jaraisyn, let's put the performance aside for a minute. The logic of the query is false. It doesn't do what you think it is doing.

Comment: @jaraisyn, better but still strange. you are doing nothing with **t2**

Comment: `d.year = t.year`. You have no table aliased as `d`. Did you mean `e`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you make a mistale because `select count(*) from table` always will give you the same answer. My suggestion is you need something like

```
select count(*) over (partition by t.type) as nlp
     , t.* 
from table t  
left outer join employee e on e.emp_id = t.emp_id
left outer join table2 t2 on t2.code= t.code and d.year = t.year 
order by e.name
```

or if you want get count only for N L P

```
select case when t.type IN ('N','L','P') THEN 
        count(*) over (partition by t.type)  
       END as nlp
     , t.* 
from table t  
left outer join employee e on e.emp_id = t.emp_id
left outer join table2 t2 on t2.code= t.code and d.year = t.year 
order by e.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Without an order_by_clause, no guarantee exists that the same query executed more than once will retrieve rows in the same order. 
also `orderby` when used with sub-queries or aggregated queries may take on performance.The only way to retrieve data from the database in some sorted order is to include an ORDER BY on your query. There is no substitute for `ORDER BY`.However you can avoid sub-queries by using joins ,they will give you some performance boost and expectedness.

Also if sorting order isnt necessary you can use group by in the end.Its also enhances the performance but you may get different order of names every time.